# fprintf that uses constant space

Tags: c, printf

I have the problem with fprintf. What I want is to use as much of space as possible staying in the same column but that means changing amount of decimal floating numbers. I have a bit problem to describe it so maybe just example:

```
0.001234
0.123456
1.234567
12.34567
123.4567
```

I tried to play with g and f options but it didn't work for me (i.e. things like `%8.6g` or `%8.6f`).

Comment: Can you provide us a better example of what you want ?

Comment: Reformatting your question (including quoted blocks) to show the desired layout can help clarify your request and thus get help.

Comment: There may not be a single format spec that can do what you want, so you may need to choose at runtime from a couple of alternatives depending on the value to be printed. I think `%.7g` for numbers >= 1.0 and `%5f` for numbers <= 1.0 will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky to survive corner cases.

With different precision specifiers, the number of digits of the left side of the decimal point changes.

```
printf("%.3f", 9.996) --> "9.996";
printf("%.2f", 9.996) --> "10.00"; // Same print width with different precision.
```

Given the various rounding modes, +/- numbers, NaN, INF, and details of the typical binary representation of floating point numbers, attempting to predict the width a `printf()` for a given floating point number is, at best, an approximation.  Rather than out-think `printf()`, simple `sprintf()` with a best guess precision.  Use `sprintf()` return value and adjust the precision as needed.

Solution:

1. Estimate width.
2. Print to a buffer.
3. Adjust if needed.

.

```
#include <float.h>
int fprintf_Width(FILE *outf, double a, int width) {
  // Subtract 2 for a potential leading "0."
  int prec = width - 2;
  if (prec < 0 || prec > 100 /* TBD upper bound */)
    return 0;  // `width` out of range

  // By some means, determine the approximate precision needed.
  char buf[1 + 1 + DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 1 + prec + 1];
  int len = sprintf(buf, "%#.*f", prec, a);
  prec -= len - width;
  if (prec < 0)
    return 0;  // `a` too big

  // Try it out
  len = sprintf(buf, "%#.*f", prec, a);

  // Adjust as needed
  if (len > width) {
    prec--;
    if (prec < 0)
      return 0;  // `a` too big
    sprintf(buf, "%#.*f", prec, a);
  }
  len = fprintf(outf, "%s", buf);
  return len;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, except that my compiler had problem with declaration of `char buf[...`, worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Acknowledgement:** This approach fails with certain numbers with certain width-specifications, as pointed out in the comments.*

One thing you could do is to calculate the amount of digits before the decimal point, and then use the [`printf` Precision Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ecbz014.aspx) to truncate the digits that would make the number too long.

- You could create a custom function, taking the `FILE` pointer to use with `fprintf`, `float` nubmer that you want to print and the desired amount of characters you want to have; 3 arguments.
- The next thing you should do is to determine the amount of digits there before the decimal point. Having a new `int` variable and putting the `float` you have into it, then dividing the new `int` by `10`s until it is zero should do it. But beware, `0.001234` also has one digit before the decimal point, although its `int` evaluation would not show one.
- Then all you'd have to do is to reduce the width received by the amount of digits before the decimal point, plus 1 for the decimal point itself (or rather minus in this case), and this shall be your Precision Specification for the `fprintf` you'll use.

So, in the end, your `fprintf` should look somewhat like this with this method:

```
fprintf( fp, "%.*f", Width - digitsbeforeDpoint - 1 );
```

Here is an example that I've done, working as far as I can test. It also has some further precautions, making sure that every input is reasonable and assuring that the float given is qualified to print out the amount of digits you'd desire:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fixdLengthfprintf( FILE * _File, float a, int width ) {
    if ( !_File ) return;
    if ( width < 3 ) return;

    int b = a;
    do {
        width--;
        b /= 10;
    } while ( b );
    width--;

    if ( width > 0 ) fprintf( _File, "%.*f\n", width, a );
}

int main( ) {

    float numbers[7] = {    // prints as:
        1.123456,           // 1.123456
        12.1234567,         // 12.12346 (apparently rounded)
        123456.0123456,     // 123456.0 (heavily rounded)
        1234567.0123456,    // doesn't get printed
        12345678.0123456,   // doesn't get printed
        123456789.0123456,  // doesn't get printed
        0.123456789,        // 0.123457
    };

        // I don't allow them to get printed because else they'd look like:
        // 1.123456
        // 12.12346
        // 123456.0
        // 1234567
        // 12345678.000000
        // 123456792.000000
        // 0.123457

    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) fixdLengthfprintf( stdout, numbers[i], 8 );

    fflush( stdin );
    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This approach fails when `a` is just under a power of 10 and `width` is about equal to  or less than `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` due to the `fprintf()` displaying a rounded numbers that shifts the decimal point.  `b` calculation does not account for that.  Try `fixdLengthfprintf(stdout, , 999.99994, 6)`.

Comment: @chux That is true and a nice example; and I give up, I was unable to correct that specific issue in any simplistic way, without changing the method I approach with.